# Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated

Tags: php

i have done some research into the source of the errors whilst setting up Built2Go Car Dealer and need help adjusting the code

**Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\speedyautos\install.php on line 185**

**lines 182 to 200 read**

```
if ($level == "4")
{

                $Install = &new INSTALL();
                $Install->INSTALLS();
                if ($Install->InstallError)
                {
                                $GetResult = "<div class=\"error\">Style Import Failed. Error below: <br /><br />$Install->InstallError</div>";
                                $submitbtn = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"level\" value=\"4\" /><input class=\"button\" type=\"submit\" name=\"next\" value=\"Redo to Step 4\" /></form></div>\n";
                }
                else
                {
                                $GetResult = "<div class=\"error\">$Install->msg</div>";
                                $GetResult .= "<a href='admincp/index.php'>Login to Your Admin</a></p>
              <p align=\"center\">Thank you for the Installing The $name_of_site Script. It is required to Delete this install script once done.</p>\n";

                                $submitbtn = "<div class=\"boxcontent\">Finished</div></form>\n";

                }
```

**Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\speedyautos\admincp\func.php on line 434**

**lines 429 to 439 read**

```
    $CarInfo = new Cars($db);
            $CarInfo->GetMostPopular();
            if (!eregi("admincp", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
            {
                            $db = new DBM;
                            $Booth = &new Booth($db);
                            if ($SystemInfo->_systemstatus['Display_Poll'] == 'A')
                            {
                                            $Poll = $Booth->display_booth();
                            }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `&` before 'new` for.e.g

`$Install = &new INSTALL();` should be `$Install = new INSTALL();`

**Added**

Same holds for `$Booth = &new Booth($db);`
it should be `$Booth = new Booth($db);`

Comment: sorry i made a mistake with the second part and have rephrased the question

Answer (score 2):

```
$Install = &new INSTALL();
```

`&` sign in this case is pointless since in php 5 objects are passed by reference (or to be clear: references to objects are passed by value).

Comment: sorry i made a mistake with the second part and have rephrased the question

Comment: @jeansymolanza: the answer is the same